# How to effectively communicate my visa status when applying for US jobs?

Tags: job-search, united-states, visa

I'm currently in the middle/end application process for my IR1 visa and looking for a job in the US in the mean time.

What would be the best way to put this on my initial application considering sometimes I can only send a resume and cover letter?

Comment: Assuming your IR1 is issued, wouldn't you have full authorization to work in the US without any conditions? Is there any reason you would need to refer to this at all in a job application?

Comment: @brhans Since my experience is mostly outside the US and I'm currently located overseas, I'd like to be upfront about being able to work without any problems (as long as it doesn't involve jobs only US citizens can, such as the Army).

Because of my resume I've had a few HR people say they can't sponsor me, even though I've been open about the visa in my cover letter.

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the best way to put this on my initial application
>   considering sometimes I can only send a resume and cover letter?

The obvious solution is to clearly communicate your visa status in your cover letter.

Additionally, be sure to indicate what you expect a potential employer to do for you regarding your visa, if anything.

Comment: So the cover letter is a better place to put this? I've been trying it and haven't got good results for the past month, but  I'll keep trying :)

Comment: @gdavis123 how do you define "good results?" There are many variables that determine how an employer responds -- might not have anything to do with your visa.